# Can you get the current project from an Analyzer?

Tags: roslyn-code-analysis

I’d like to write a Analyzer that adds either `Option Strict Off` or `Option Strict On`, which seems like it would be easy to do ... if the Analyzer can get access to a files project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context has a property Compilation, which has the property CommonOptions a VisualBasicCompilationOptions, which has the Property OptionStrict which allows me to determine if the project has strict on as a default or not.